# Hangfire failed jobs logs: how to sort them?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, sorting, hangfire

I'm using the latest version of Hangifre (*1.6.17*) and Hangfire.Mongo (*0.5.5*) and I'm having troubles sorting the Hangfire failed jobs logs.

Currently they're sorted in ascending order (older logs appearing first) and I'd like to have them sorted in descending order.

I've seen some screenshots where people had their logs properly sorted by the timestamp thus I know it's possible to do this but I didn't find anything useful in the documentation.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Should be a bug in Mongo storage. I even believe it‘s not the only sorting issue there after they’ve changed identifiers to ObjectId. Try opening an issue on github.

Comment: Thanks for your input Alex. I already opened up an issue on github https://github.com/sergeyzwezdin/Hangfire.Mongo/issues/116

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alex suggested in the comment - this is indeed a sorting bug in Hangfire.Mongo library which will be fixed in one of the next releases. This was confirmed by the devs on lib's github page and you can access the issue via link in the comment above.

A temporary workaround could be logging the files via [custom logger class](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/configuring-logging.html) to avoid spending considerable time searching through the dashboard logs.